# ng-include não funciona após usar uma diretiva

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directives

eu precisei fazer um controller dinamico, porém quando uso a diretiva `data-ng-dynamic-controller` o meu ng-include não funciona alguém sabe oque pode ser?

> Diretiva ng-dynamic-controller

```
appModule.directive('ngDynamicController', ['$compile', '$parse',function($compile, $parse) {
    return {
        scope: {
            name: '=ngDynamicController'
        },
        restrict: 'A',
        terminal: true,
        priority: 100000,
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            elem.attr('ng-controller', scope.name);
            elem.removeAttr('data-ng-dynamic-controller');
            elem.removeAttr('ng-dynamic-controller');

            $compile(elem)(scope);
        }
    };
}]);
```

> HTML

```
<div class="page-content-wrapper" data-ng-controller="masterpageController as mpc">

    <div class="page-content" ng-dynamic-controller="mpc.getController()">
            <div class="page-head">
                <div class="page-title">
                    <h1>{{pageTitle}}
                        <small>{{pageDescription}}</small>
                    </h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <ul class="page-breadcrumb breadcrumb">
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:;">AppName</a>
                    <i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span class="active">{{pageTitle}}</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- Não funciona... -->
            <div data-ng-include="mpc.getHtmlFile()"></div>

        </div>
</div>
```

Obs: mpc é o meu `masterpageController`, e ambos os métodos existem e o retorno está correto porém quando uso a `ng-dynamic-controller` o método `getHtmlFile()` nem é chamado. Caso eu remova o `ng-dynamic-controller` funciona normalmente o `getHtmlFile()`

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver galera, aparentemente é o `terminal` removi ele o o `priority` e funcionou normalmente.

```
appModule.directive('ngDynamicController', ['$compile', '$parse',function($compile, $parse) {
    return {
        scope: {
            name: '=ngDynamicController'
        },
        restrict: 'A',
        terminal: true,
        priority: 100000,
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            elem.attr('ng-controller', scope.name);
            elem.removeAttr('data-ng-dynamic-controller');
            elem.removeAttr('ng-dynamic-controller');

            $compile(elem)(scope);
        }
    };
}]);
```